# A comparison between model training approaches

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-science, kaggle

Suppose that I have a dataset, and due to limitations imposed by Kaggle Notebook Environments, I have decided to split a large dataset into "blocks"; A, B and C. In addition, I would like to train the model for 10 epochs. Does it make a difference if I train the model as follows:

A ---> 10 epochs

B ---> 10 epochs

C ---> 10 epochs

Compared to this approach:

A ---> B ---> C [Epoch 1] ---> A ---> B ---> C [Epoch 2] ---> … ---> A ---> B ---> C [Epoch 10]

Furthermore, if there is a difference which I think there is but not sure, is one approach better than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For machine learning, basically you will have to put all the training data altogether so that your model won't miss any of the pattern that your dataset contains. And I would said that there is a big step before you train your model which is **Shuffle**. Imagining that you was ask to do pure math all the time, and suddenly your teacher put you in front of a geography problem and ask you to solve it, you will be kind of unknowing what to do somehow, machine it's the same! So be sure to use all the data to train your model and if your A--->B--->C [Epoch 1] is a shuffled data, then that's great, or you have to shuffle it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I have shuffled the dataset before splitting it into blocks A, B, C,... then the second approach is better than the first where I train each block for 10 epochs before moving on to the next. Is that right?

Comment: In this case, I will say **YES**